# Pyspark: pyspark.sql.utils column ambigous

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df = df.withColumn("ID", df["ID"].cast("int"))

df = df.withColumn("ID_Check" , when(df["ID"] == 1), 1).otherwise(0))
```

**I am getting Ambiguous.**

```
ID could be : ID, ID.
```

Didn't get it I tried with `drop("ID")` but still same issue.

How do we resolve this

Comment: what is df.columns ?

Comment: It has ID, NAME, CITY,

Comment: ```df.withColumn("ID_Check" , when(df["ID"] == 1, 1).otherwise(0))``` ?

Comment: I just considering 1 values not considering 0.5, 0, whatever it is setting '0'. Issue is with column Ambiguos i think not with the condition

Comment: your condition in the code is wrong, it won't execute. please correct it.

Comment: Ok, What about column ambiguous

Comment: Can you do a .show() and display the data frame. Usually ambiguous error comes when you have two columns with same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df = df.withColumn("ID", col("ID").cast("int"))
df = df.withColumn("ID_Check" , when(col("ID") == 1), 1).otherwise(0))
```